# can i execute a PHP method inside a class with Ubuntu CLI

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, command-line

I have a large Laravel application and i want to execute a method that will send a mail without using any Front-End trigger. 
I heard that there is a way to execute this method with the command line but i have no idea how to do so.

P.S. Should i trigger the PHP file itself or the 'routes.php' somehow, or is there another way?

Comment: Here you go: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan

Comment: Voting to close this as too broad. Presumably the issue is in creating the content to go in the email (otherwise you don't need PHP at all, nevermind Laravel). How you create the content depends on the structure of your application and we can't tell you whether that works outside of a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `php artisan tinker` which is a Php Repl that bootstraps your Laravel appplication. also it is recommended to write Artisan Commands for the purpose.